# Does a compact embedded manifold achieve all unit normals?

Tags: differential-geometry

Fix some compact $n-1$ dimensional manifold $M$ without boundary embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any unit vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, does there exist 
a point $p\in M$ at which the unit normal vector is $v$?

I think the result holds if $n=2$, because the only compact 
$1$-dimensional manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are diffeomorphic to the 
circle, so should achieve all unit normals. Intuitively, it seems reasonable that this should hold for $n=3$ as well.

This feels like it's just basic geometry and there should be a proof for it around somewhere, but I haven't found it yet.

I think an equivalent question goes something like: if the level set $S=f^{-1}(y)$ of a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is non-empty and 'finite' in some sense, does $\frac{\nabla f}{\left|\left|\nabla f\right|\right|}$ achieve all values of the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ on $S$?

Comment: the normal at the point where $v \cdot p$ is maximized is $v$.

Comment: Manfold?  Yuck yuck puke puke!  It's manifold.  Edit PLEASE!!!

Comment: I believe that the answer given here: [Gauss Map Surjective?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389196/prove-that-gauss-map-on-m-is-surjective) by @Ragib Zaman actually generalizes to arbitrary dimension. Your question is equivalent.