# Components of normal vector field of hypersurface

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Let $\Sigma^d\subset \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ be a smoothly immersed closed (compact without boundary) hypersurface. If $\Sigma$ is orientable, the normal vector field $\mathbf{n}:\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ can be written as $$\mathbf{n}(x)=(n_1(x),\dots,n_{d+1}(x))$$ for some functions $n_i:\Sigma\to \mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** Are the functions $\{n_i\}$ linearly independent?

The example I am thinking of is when $\Sigma$ is the unit sphere. For example, when $d=1$, then $n_1(x)=\cos(x)$ and $n_2(x)=\sin(x)$, which are linearly independent.

On the contrary, if $\Sigma$ is a hyperplane, then $\mathbf{n}$ is constant, so each $n_i$ is constant, and thus the $n_i$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Yes in the case of the sphere. If $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb R$ are such that $\sum_i \alpha_i n_i(x) =0$ for all $x\in \mathbb S^d$, then we obtain $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{d+1})$ is perpendicular to all unit vectors, since $n(x)=x$. The only vector perpendicular to all vectors is $0$ and therefore $\alpha =0$. 

So, the functions $n_i(x)=x_i$ are all linearly independent.

Comment: The result seems true also in the case $n:\Sigma \to \mathbb S^d$ has an interior point on the image. That is the case because you can choose $x_1,\ldots,x_{d+1} \in \Sigma$ such that $n(x_1),\ldots,n(x_{d+1})$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^{d+1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It implies that whenever the Gauss map is surjective, the answer to the question is true. But the Gauss map is always surjective for a closed orientable hypersurface, (the argument in this post holds for any dimension: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389196/prove-that-gauss-map-on-m-is-surjective#389213).

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that!