# Is a normal vector field surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be open, bounded and with smooth boundary. Then $\partial \Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a closed and compact $(n - 1)$-dimensional manifold. Let $\nu : \partial \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb S^{n - 1}$ be the unique continuous unit outer normal vector field.

**Question:** Is $\nu$ surjective?

I tried to fiddle around with a little bit of antipodal constructions (if I can show, that the antipodal vector is in the image, I could maybe have used the mean value theorem) or with relative topologies (assume $z \in \mathbb S^{n - 1}$ is not in the image of $\nu$. Then maybe the mapping degree helps leading to a contradiction since a hole would arise in the image). However, I was not able to come to a conclusion.

I would be grateful for ideas and/or references. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if $\Omega$ is an infinite cylinder?

Comment: @KurtG. then $\partial\Omega$ wouldn’t be compact…

Comment: Correct. But the infinite cylinder is without doubt open and has a smooth boundary. @DarkViole7 Perhaps you may want to reconsider the assumptions.

Comment: @KurtG Thank you for the comment, I added that $\Omega$ has to be bounded.

Comment: I found an alternative argument for the surjectivity, which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389196/prove-that-gauss-map-on-m-is-surjective). The argument for a) is also valid in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach you should think through: Choose $w\in S^{n-1}$ and consider the function $f\colon \Omega\to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x\cdot w$. By compactness of $M=\partial\Omega$, the function attains both a maximum and a minimum on $M$. Note that $\nu(p)=+w$ when $f$ has a local maximum at $p$ and $\nu(p)=-w$ when $f$ has a local minimum at $p$.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot!